# django - AttributeError - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am creating activity streams for the user using signals and content types. The activities are being created by the post_save signals. However I am getting problems displaying those activities in the template.

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /user/user_activities/

'unicode' object has no attribute 'META'
```

And the line shown as the error is this line:

```
{{ activity.get_rendered_html }}
```

I have no idea as to why I am getting this error. I would really be very much grateful if you could show me how to solve this problem. Thank you.

This is the model for activity:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ("%s %s") % (self.actor.username, self.action)

    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.content_type.name)
        return render(template_name, {
            'object':self.content_object,
            'actor':self.actor,
            'action':self.action,
        })
```

Template for `get_rendered_html()`:

```
<div class="user_activity">
    <p>{{ actor.username }} {{ action }} {{ object.user }}'s status</p>

    <p>{{ object.body }}</p>

    {% if object.image %}
        <div class="activity_img_wrapper">
            <p><img src="/media/{{ object.image }}"/></p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

And in the views:

```
def user_activities(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(actor=user)
    return render(request,'user_activites.html', {
        'activities_of':user,
        'activities':activities
    })
```

Lastly in the templates:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="activities_wrapper">
        {% if activities.count > 0 %}
            {% for activity in activities %}
                <div class="activity">
                    {{ activity.get_rendered_html }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div class="activity">
                <p>No activity</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `Activity.get_rendered_html()` method.

`django.shortcuts.render` expects `request` object as it's first parameter.  You should use `render_to_string` instead of `render`:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def get_rendered_html(self):
    template_name = '%s_activity.html' %(self.content_type.name)
    return render_to_string(template_name, {
        'object':self.content_object,
        'actor':self.actor,
        'action':self.action,
    })
```